# Speed up slow mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to improve performance for an application. I might need to create summary tables that run on cron so the app doesn't take as long to load (5-10 seconds). Is that the best idea?

Given the following table:

```
mysql> describe school_data_sets_numeric_data;
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_set_nid | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| school_nid   | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year         | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value        | decimal(18,5) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following queries (run once for each data_set_nid for a school)

This query runs fast (0 seconds):

```
SELECT year, description, CONCAT(FORMAT((value/(SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM `school_data_sets_numeric_data` as numeric_data_inner 
WHERE year = numeric_data_outer.year and data_set_nid = numeric_data_outer.data_set_nid and school_nid = numeric_data_outer.school_nid)) * 100, 2), '%') as value 
FROM `school_data_sets_numeric_data` as numeric_data_outer 
WHERE data_set_nid = 38251 and school_nid = 32805 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type | possible_keys                               | key          | key_len | ref                                                                                                       | rows | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | numeric_data_outer | ref  | data_set_nid,data_set_nid_2,school_nid      | data_set_nid | 8       | const,const                                                                                               |   17 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | numeric_data_inner | ref  | year,data_set_nid,data_set_nid_2,school_nid | data_set_nid | 8       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.numeric_data_outer.data_set_nid,rocdocs_main_drupal_7.numeric_data_outer.school_nid |    9 | Using where                 |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

This query runs slow (1.43 seconds):

```
SELECT year, description, CONCAT(FORMAT((SUM(value)/(SELECT SUM(value) 
FROM `school_data_sets_numeric_data` as numeric_data_inner 
WHERE year = numeric_data_outer.year and data_set_nid = numeric_data_outer.data_set_nid)) * 100, 2), '%') as value 
FROM `school_data_sets_numeric_data` as numeric_data_outer 
WHERE data_set_nid = 38251 GROUP BY year,description ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type | possible_keys                    | key            | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | numeric_data_outer | ref  | data_set_nid,data_set_nid_2      | data_set_nid_2 | 4       | const | 90640 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | numeric_data_inner | ref  | year,data_set_nid,data_set_nid_2 | year           | 4       | func  | 38871 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How many different `school_nid` are there in your table?

Comment: There are 5446 different school_nids

Answer (score -1):

Correlated subqueries/subselects are often a bottelneck - partly due to the fact that MySql only has a nested loop join algorithm and no hash-joins/merge-joins.

I would try joining your main select to a derived table holding all the SUM values you need.